# Shutil attempts to copy directories that don't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, shutil, copying

I'm attempting to copy the Documents folder under the Windows userprofile, the `shutil.copytree(documents, destination)` works partially. It will copy the Documents to the root of the destination, in this case the `R:` drive, and it will also attempt to copy the other Windows special folders (My Music, My Pictures, etc..), even if they don't exist under Documents.

```
import shutil


def main():

   try:

       user_profile = os.getenv("USERPROFILE")

       # Construct a full path to the documents folder 
       documents = Path(user_profile).joinpath("Documents")

       # Destination for the Documents folder
       destination = Path("R:\\Test")

       shutil.copytree(documents, destination)            

   except (FileNotFoundError, shutil.Error) as error:
       print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is a excerpt of the exception that is thrown:

```
[('C:\\Users\\ConsoleGeek\\Documents\\My Music', 'R:\\Test\\My Music', 
"[WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\ConsoleGeek\\\\Documents\\\\My Music'")
...
```

None of these folders exists under Documents, so I don't fully understand why `shutil` attempts to copy these special folders. If I attempt to copy a regular folder under the user profile, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Windows system well enough but you could try calling

```
shutil.copytree(documents, destination, symlinks=True)
```

if these 'special folders' are symbolic links (or the Windows equivalent of symbolic links).

Comment: `symlinks=true` doesn't work. It comes back as false when I test it with `is_symlink()`. It could be a bug with `shutil.copytree()`, but the weird part is why does it attempt to copy `Documents\My Music`, `Documents\My Pictures`, etc, even if the request wasn't given in code and the directories don't exist there. `xcopy` in batch and `Copy-Item` in Powershell both do the job properly. Copying normal folders with `shutil.copytree()` works, so I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: I'll post a more detail overview about what I'm experiencing when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

To understand why [`copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) attempts to copy [special folders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder) when attempting to copy `Documents`, we have to first look at the hidden files.

**Using cmd.exe:**

If we open `cmd.exe` and change the directory to `Documents`, we can run [`dir /A:H /B`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to see all the folders (including hidden ones).

```
C:\Users\ConsoleGeek\Documents>dir /A:H /B
desktop.ini
My Music
My Pictures
My Videos
```

**Using Powershell**:

If we open `powershell.exe` and type [`Get-ChildItem -Force -File -Path .\Documents\`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-display-hidden-files-by-using-powershell/), it will list all the items in the `Documents` folder.

**Note**: It doesn't display the special folders.

```
PS C:\Users\ConsoleGeek> Get-ChildItem -Force -File -Path .\Documents\


    Directory: C:\Users\ConsoleGeek\Documents


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a-hs-        10/4/2019   6:00 PM            402 desktop.ini
```

**Using Python**:

I ran the following code in VSCode:

```
def main():

    try:
        user_profile = os.getenv("USERPROFILE")
        documents = Path(user_profile).joinpath("Documents")

        for item in documents.iterdir():
            print(item)

    except (FileNotFoundError, shutil.Error) as error:
       print(error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


# Output:
C:\Users\ConsoleGeek\Documents\desktop.ini
C:\Users\ConsoleGeek\Documents\My Music
C:\Users\ConsoleGeek\Documents\My Pictures
C:\Users\ConsoleGeek\Documents\My Videos
```

**Using File Explorer**:

If I selected the option to show hidden files, the `Documents` folder is still empty.

**Copying Recursively**:

**Using cmd.exe**:

Using the `xcopy` command with the `/E` `/H` switches we can copy all every folder/file including empty and hidden ones.

```
C:\Users\ConsoleGeek>xcopy Documents R:\Sync\Documents /E /H
Documents\desktop.ini
Access denied
Unable to create directory - R:\Sync\Documents\My Music
1 File(s) copied
```

The `1 File(s) copied` is misleading because when you enable the Show Hidden files, you can verify nothing is copied.

**Using Powershell**:

Using the `Copy-Item` cmdlet with the `-Recurse` switch, we get an access denied error, similar to `cmd.exe`.

This is an excerpt of the error message.

```
Copy-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\ConsoleGeek\Documents\My Music' is denied.
```

**Solutions**:

**Using cmd.exe**:

`xcopy` has the `/Exclude:filename.txt` parameter. You provide a file with folder/file names you want to exclude.

```
My Music
My Pictures
My Video
desktop.ini
```

and use it with the `xcopy` command:

```
C:\Users\ConsoleGeek>xcopy Documents R:\Sync\Documents /E /H /EXCLUDE:filenames.txt
```

**Using Powershell**:

The `-Exclude` parameter doesn't work with the `-Recurse` parameter, so it will just copy the empty My Music, My ... folders. To exclude them from the being copied, you can provide a wildcard to the `-Exclude` parameter.

```
Copy-Item -Path .\Documents\ -Destination "R:\Sync\Documents" -Exclude ("My*", ".ini")
```

If you need to copy sub directories, but exclude some, you can build a list of directories you don't want copied and loop through the `Documents` folder and check each item against the list. You may need to experiment to see what fits your requirements.

**Using Python**:

Depending on the requirements your script will obviously be a little different, but you can use this function to filter out the special folders, and `.ini` file.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
from typing import Tuple
from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns


def copy_documents_folder(source: Path, destination: Path, ext_to_ignore: Tuple):
    copytree(source, destination, ignore = ignore_patterns(*ext_to_ignore))

def main():

   try:

       user_profile = os.getenv("USERPROFILE")
       documents = Path(user_profile).joinpath("Documents")
       destination = Path("R:\\Sync\\Documents")

       copy_documents_folder(source=documents, destination=destination, 
       ext_to_ignore=("*.ini", "My *"))


   except (FileNotFoundError, shutil.Error) as error:
       print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```